# Request for parallels between Psalms and Proverbs

Tags: psalms, proverbs

Can someone either post themselves or give me a link to a somewhat detailed comparison between Psalms and Proverbs where fairly word for word parallels are found?

I am looking for all the instances where the author of a Proverb cites a Psalm or vice versa.

---

For instance:

> **[Psalm 37:1](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=ps%2037:1;pr%2024:19&version=ESV)** (ESV)
> <sup>1</sup> Fret not yourself because of evildoers;
>    be not envious of wrongdoers!
>
> **[Proverbs 24:19](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=pr%2024:19;ps%2037:1;&version=ESV)** (ESV)
> <sup>19</sup> Fret not yourself because of evildoers,
>    and be not envious of the wicked,

---

> **[Psalm 37:9](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=ps%2037:9;%20%20prov%2023:18&version=ESV)** (ESV)
> <sup>9</sup> For the evildoers shall be cut off,
>    but those who wait for the LORD shall inherit the land.
>
> **[Proverbs 23:18](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=%20prov%2023:18;%20ps%2037:9&version=ESV)** (ESV)
> <sup>18</sup> Surely there is a future,
>    and your hope will not be cut off.

---

> **[Psalm 37:16](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=%20ps%2037:16;prov%2015:16%20&version=ESV)** (ESV)
> <sup>16</sup> Better is the little that the righteous has
>    than the abundance of many wicked.
>
> **[Proverbs 15:16](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=%20prov%2015:16%20;%20ps%2037:16&version=ESV)** (ESV)
> <sup>16</sup> Better is a little with the fear of the LORD
>    than great treasure and trouble with it.

**Note:** Psalm 37 is the best example of what I'm asking for.

Comment: I've been having dificulty findingthis on google so i came here

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics.SE.  This is a pretty broad question and there may not be any such parallels, so I wouldn't hold up much hope for an answer.  Maybe you could help us out by letting us know _why_ you are asking the question.  Do you have some reason to suspect there are parallels?

Comment: I agree that motivation may lead to richer answers. Additionally, a comparison between Proverbs and Egyptian Wisdom Literature would be a much more satisfying study.

Comment: Im looking for 1) anywhere where a psalmist quotes a proverb or where a proverb writer quotes words from a psalm 2) anywhere where a psalmist takes almost word for word an idea from a proverb or a proverb writer takes an idea from a verse in a psalm and 3) anywhere where it looks or seems like that is happening

Comment: that or if someone could suggest a web link to a site that is doing a similar study would be great. One reason im doing this study is to find the ground for the origin of each psalm. It is easy to find when at the beginning of a psalm it is stated "written when David ..." but for other psalms it is much more difficult to figure out the background of their origin

Comment: the second reason im looking for this is for bible daily reading purposes. I like to read kings and chronicles together with the prophets to get an idea of what was happening from the historical point of view and then what was happening from the view of the prophets. So i am trying to peice the psalms into scripture in fitting locations. It's for personal reading and family reading

Comment: Interesting. Now you've got me all excited about the idea of getting a unicode version of the BHS and doing an overlapping phrase search using some nerdy programming. I've done it with the NT, why not the OT!!!

Comment: Here are some good examples I've found so far

Comment: Here are some good examples I've found so far 1) ps 37:1 and prov 24:19 or 23:17-18 2) ps 37:9 and prov 23:18 3) ps :16 and prov 15:16 note) psalm 37 is the best example of what I'm asking for

Comment: I pulled in those examples, which are really interesting.  Since Psalm 37 says it's "Of David" the natural reading is that it came first and Solomon copied it.  But, of course, both could have relied on an even earlier source.  Thanks for keeping at the comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With what you've stated in the comments (that one reason you are doing this is for reading the Bible historically), these could be a big help to you.

[Chronological Study Bible Reading Plan](http://www.nelsonbibles.com/admin/uploads/pdfs/ChronologicalReadingPlan.pdf)

[A more detailed reading plan](http://www.ewordtoday.com/year/).  This site has several plans available which may benefit you such as the historical and chronological plans.  The difference being that the historical plan places the chapters on the estimated date of their *writing* while the chronological plan places them based on when the events described happened.  Though you use the word "historically," their chronological plan is closer to what you describe.  For example, April 13th has 1Sam 18-20; Ps 11/59 because the writing of those two psalms were linked to the events of 1 Sam 18-20.  You will also note that that psalms are not listed in numerical order.

I hope you find what you are looking for.

Comment: That's good advice.  I did a chronological plan a few years ago and it was very helpful for getting an idea about when certain prophets were active and so on.  If I recall correctly, all of Proverbs was placed in the same time frame as Solomon, who is the usual suspect for their authorship.

Comment: thanks a ton Frank. I think you're right. And your answer. Is pronounced the closest I'm going to get to what I'm requesting it's very helpful. Thank you

Comment: Though beyond psalm and proverbs: Ps 1:3  And he shall be like a tree planted by the rivers of water, that bringeth forth his fruit in his season; his leaf also shall not wither; and whatsoever he doeth shall prosper.
Jer 17:8  For he shall be as a tree planted by the waters, and that spreadeth out her roots by the river, and shall not see when heat cometh, but her leaf shall be green; and shall not be careful in the year of drought, neither shall cease from yielding fruit.

Comment: Job 21:18  They are as stubble before the wind, and as chaff that the storm carrieth away.
Ps 1:4  The ungodly are not so: but are like the chaff which the wind driveth away.
Ps 35:5  Let them be as chaff before the wind: and let the angel of the LORD chase them.

Comment: Jud 15:14  And when he came unto Lehi, the Philistines shouted against him: and the Spirit of the LORD came mightily upon him, and the cords that were upon his arms became as flax that was burnt with fire, and his bands loosed from off his hands.
Ps 2:3  Let us break their bands asunder, and cast away their cords from us.

Comment: That's what I do all day long... just correlate scripture.

Answer (score 0):

What you looking for is the Correlation between Psalms and Proverbs.
Checkout the same phrase as a section within this research paper

https://www.scirp.org/journal/paperinformation.aspx?paperid=20943

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! Hello, Brice. This is considered a "link-only" answer. It would be helpful for future visitors to this question if you would [edit] in a summary of that page. Links can become broken or outdated so a summary would still provide the necessary information.